# Crystal Reports - Does a delimited string contain a certain element, and if so, what position in the string?

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

So I have a report that I'm trying to design, and arrays are proving to be a challenge.

Some of the commissions we pay are split between different sales reps, and I need to be able to filter a running total formula based on whether or not the rep is part of the list.  I also need to know where in the array, position 1 or 2, as the percentage due to each rep is different.

I started with a simple test:

```
if InStr({BAQReportResult.InvcHead.SalesRepList}, {BAQReportParameter.Character01}) > 0 then True else False
```

This doesn't work as it reports as true regardless of where the rep falls in the array.

Since a pic is worth a thousand words...

I have 5 detail sections, each one corresponding with a position in the array, as we could potentially have a 5 way commission split on an order.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGUKx.png
(sorry, not enough rep points to properly post an image)

Each detail section corresponds with the appropriate rep rate...

Detail section a (in red) should return as false, because WI is not first in the list.  Detail section b (in green) should return true.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pY6K.png

Please let me know if I need to provide more info, and thank you for any ideas or help!

Comment: When you say "array", do you really mean a delimited string? Array is a CR data type and does not work with the `InStr()` function.

Comment: Yeah, probably...the raw data is separated by ~ when I run the query.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, Ryan, I've updated the title, hopefully it sounds like I know what I'm looking for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (very basic) example of how to accomplish this. First, the string is split up into a true array object, then you're able to iterate over the elements of the array and simply return the index if the string is found.

```
local stringvar array tmp := split("John~James~Frank", '~'); //create array from string
local numbervar i:=1;

while i<=ubound(tmp) do
 if "Frank"=tmp[i] then exit while else (i:=i+1; true);

if i>ubound(tmp) then 0 //string not found
 else i //return the matching string's array index
```